# Clang 5.1 fpmath

Tags: macos, clang

I am trying to compile a program with Clang 5.1, as included in Xcode 5.1. This program is an early-stage boot loader, and as such its execution environment is very limited. I must pass the `-mfpmath=387` compiler flag to produce correct assembly. When I upgraded to Xcode 5.1, I received the following error:

`error: the '387' unit is not supported with this instruction set`

Does anyone know what this error means? Did the syntax for this flag change, and, if so, what is the new syntax? (I am also interested in knowing what `-mfpmath=387` *does*. I copied it verbatim [from a Makefile in `boot-132`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/boot/boot-132/i386/boot2/Makefile), but never really understood its effect on the compilation procedure.)

Comment: The flag `-mfpmath=387` instructs the compiler to use the 80387 compatible floating point instructions only. This is required because your bootloader may run on machines that don't have MMX or SSE support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, for Clang to accept `-mfpmath=387`, I had to also pass `-mno-sse`. I found this out by grepping Clang’s source. I still want to know what `-mfpmath=387` does, though.

Comment: As described in llvm/tools/clang/include/clang/Driver/CC1Options.td:

def mfpmath : Separate<["-"], "mfpmath">,
  HelpText<"Which unit to use for fp math">;

So you may choose 387, sse...

Answer (score 1):

Educated guess:

The 387 refers to the intel x87 floating point instruction set http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87 (hence the 'fpmath' bit of the compiler flag).

It's likely that the flag is telling the compiler to generate code targeting the 387 floating point architecture, rather than a later version.